# Index on nested JSONB field is not used

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, query-performance

I created an index on a nested JSONB field:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON some_table(cast(content->'meta'->>'version' AS int));
```

but the select query still does a full table scan:

```
select * 
from some_table 
where (content->'meta'->>'version')::INT <= 9000 
LIMIT 1;
```

I also tried to express the query like:

```
select * 
from some_table 
where cast(content->'meta'->>'version' AS INT) <= 9000 
LIMIT 1;
```

with the same result.

Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=10 width=52)
  ->  Seq Scan on some_table  (cost=0.00..38429.27 rows=361441 width=52)
        Filter: ((((content -> 'meta'::text) ->> 'version'::text))::integer <= 9000)
```

What do I miss here?

Edit: It was more a coincident. I added a `ORDER BY random()` to the query and got the following query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=31644.83..31644.83 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=31644.83..32548.43 rows=361441 width=52) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (random())
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on game_object_user  (cost=6769.60..29837.62 rows=361441 width=52) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((((content -> 'meta'::text) ->> 'version'::text))::integer < 9000)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_idx  (cost=0.00..6679.23 rows=361441 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((((content -> 'meta'::text) ->> 'version'::text))::integer < 90000)
Planning time: 0.074 ms
Execution time: 0.040 ms
```

The index was used.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a simple "explain"). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Did you try the exact same expression as in the index: `cast(content->'meta'->>'version' AS int) <= 9000`?

Comment: I added a `ORDER BY RANDOM()` and the index is used now!?

Comment: The plan for the slow query is a "simple" `explain`. Please replace the first plan in your question with the output of **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** for the _slow_ version of the query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I found the root cause. `version` was `null` for all entries. The field was not existing yet. What should I do with my question? Deleting or answering it?